# how send data in a new BrowserWindow (modal or 2e window) electron app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

In context of an Electron app, I already have a main BrowserWindow window which run my application fine.

I want to be able to send data to a new BrowserWindow. I know there is lot tricks **BUT** :

- *My second BrowserWindow is not already created. I can't use the event chain for send data* (like this tuto : [tuto send data between browserWindows](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/536/how-to-send-information-from-one-window-to-another-in-electron-framework))
- *My data are not from the database. I can't fetch/get data into a vue component lifecycle method like this*

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{data}}
  </div>
</template><script>export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  beforeMount(){
    this.getName();
  },
  methods: {
    async getName(){
      const res = await fetch('https://api.agify.io/?name=michael');
      const data = await res.json();
      this.data = data;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

- *My data are too long for sending that into the url like this*

```js
      url = params && "id" in params ? "category/edit/" + params["id"] : "category/edit"
this.browserWindow.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL + url)
```

- *My data are not from the post of the form. I can't use the loadURL method of BrowserWindow with postData property like this*

```js
win.loadURL('http://localhost:8000/post', {
  postData: [{
    type: 'rawData',
    bytes: Buffer.from('hello=world')
  }],
  extraHeaders: 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
})
```

Indeed I all know those tricks for sending data but my goal is to 'send' data into a BrowserWindow that I created in same time on the fly.

Is there a way with webContents electron ?

I would like to attach data with my creation of BrowserWindow that start the implementation like that, because I already know which data I want into my window :

```
createBrowserWindow()
{
    return new BrowserWindow({width: 650, height: 800, show: false, frame: true,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false,
            plugins: true,
            nodeIntegration: (process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION)},
            enableRemoteModule: true
    });
}
```

Comment: I haven't really worked with electron only for couple days, but how about Vuex?

Comment: Use the `ready` event, and send the data before you have shown  the new window.